# I can't add Treenode in Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I would like to add a tree node to the parent form though the child form
however it does not appear on the treeview

and I also add treeview imageIndex

please let me know how to add treenode

```
// [childform]
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   main _main = new main();
   _main.SetFtpClient();
}

//[MainForm]
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _ConnectForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
   _ConnectForm.ShowDialog(this);
}

public void SetFtpClient()
{
   TreeNode svrNode = new TreeNode("server", 0, 0);
   svrNode.Nodes.Add("SE", "seoul", 0, 0);
   svrNode.Nodes.Add("DJ", "seoul1", 0, 0);
   svrNode.Nodes.Add("BS", "seoul2", 0, 0);

   TreeNode netNode = new TreeNode("network", 1, 1);
   netNode.Nodes.Add("T1", "Cable", 1, 1);
   netNode.Nodes.Add("56K", "Modem", 1, 1);
   netNode.Nodes.Add("3G", "Wireless", 1, 1);
   tv_ftp.Nodes.Add(svrNode);
   tv_ftp.Nodes.Add(netNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is having a reference of your main form in your child form. Add a parameter in your child form constructor. Let's say that the child form's name is **ConnectForm** and the main form is **MainForm**.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewDemo
{
    public partial class ConnectForm : Form
    {
        Form parent; // a reference of the main form

        public ConnectForm(Form form)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // set a reference of the main form
            parent = form;
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // you have to cast it to the MainForm first,
            // otherwise the method SetFtpClient is not accessible
            var _main = (MainForm) parent;
            _main.SetFtpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you pass the main form into your child form using the parameterized constructor.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewDemo
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create an instance of child form, and pass the main form into it
            var _ConnectForm = new ConnectForm(this);

            _ConnectForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            _ConnectForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }

        public void SetFtpClient()
        {
            TreeNode svrNode = new TreeNode("server", 0, 0);
            svrNode.Nodes.Add("SE", "seoul", 0, 0);
            svrNode.Nodes.Add("DJ", "seoul1", 0, 0);
            svrNode.Nodes.Add("BS", "seoul2", 0, 0);

            TreeNode netNode = new TreeNode("network", 1, 1);
            netNode.Nodes.Add("T1", "Cable", 1, 1);
            netNode.Nodes.Add("56K", "Modem", 1, 1);
            netNode.Nodes.Add("3G", "Wireless", 1, 1);
            tv_ftp.Nodes.Add(svrNode);
            tv_ftp.Nodes.Add(netNode);
        }
    }
}
```